# Insert default value for serial type auto incrementation column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment, default-value

I defined an attribute in my table of type **`serial4`**, so when I insert a new row, the attribute is automatically incremented:

```
myTable (id serial4, name varchar(25), whatever whatever, ...);
```

To insert a new entry, I just strip off the `id` attribute in the association list:

```
insert into myTable (name, whatever, ...) values ('foo', ...);
```

Now, if my table has a large number of attributes, the association list is exhausting to write.
I just want to write:

```
insert into myTable values (...);
```

But if the first attribute of `myTable` is the `serial4 id`. What should I write in the `VALUES` list to get the `id` being incremented +1 from the last inserted value?

```
insert into myTable values (?, 'foo', ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) command accepts the key word `DEFAULT`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT, 'foo', ...);
```

The [`serial` pseudo data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (synonym: `serial4`) is just a notational convenience for an `integer` column that retrieves its default values from an attached `SEQUENCE`. By using the `DEFAULT` key word, the next value from the sequence is inserted like any other default value.

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Aside: it's typically not advisable to omit the target column list in persisted code. Any later change to the table will break that code it confusing ways.

Comment: I was about to ask the difference between serial4 and a sequenced integer, two birds on rock thanks

Comment: @Oddant ... and blindfolded, too! ;)